# How to fix arduino MKR 1010 not printing to serial

Tags: arduino

I just bought a new Arduino 1010 and I can't seem to print to serial. The baud rate is the same and I've updated all firmware. Any suggestions?

I tried just running a test program like this after a longer program didn't print anything to serial and neither of them print to serial.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("hello");
}
void loop() {

}
```

Comment: so uploading your code is working ok without any errors?

Comment: add `while (!Serial);` after Serial.begin